# Is there a way to change the names of Python Interpreters in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I want to know if there is a way to change the names of Python Interpreters in **VSCode** so that I could distinguish them better whenever I am switching Interpreters. The issue is that the *OpenCV* python interpreter (1st one) is always highlighted, so I didn't know I am able to change interpreters until I run a python file (*it gives a module error*).

[image]

Error: "No module named..."

[image]

I believe the only indicator here is at the bottom left corner of VSCode where it shows the current interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to do it with VSCode envs, but conda let's you name envs, which can be chosen in the same way.

Comment: if you use the `venv` module to create virtual environments the name is used in the interpreter see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: @rioV8 I'm confused why the first one is always highlighted even I select other interpreter.

Comment: they are sorted by the name and the first one is selected because 1 has to be selected. for me the env name is part of the name

Comment: @Geni-sama -It is recommended that you use this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview) to download the latest official version of VSCode.